# doubt regarding the base_local_planner::transformGlobalPlan() function

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, local-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to understand the [base_local_planner::transformGlobalPlan()](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/base_local_planner/html/namespacebase__local__planner.html#a047695bdbc63bda4b4bd5f0f5bd9b585) function.

As per my understanding, the function takes in the `global_plan` (generated by the `global planner`) as an input and updates the `transformedPlan` variable. It does so by transforming the points in the `global_plan` to the `global_frame` (of the `local costmap`) and then removing the points that lie outside the bounds of the `local costmap`.

In particular, I am trying to understand the section inside the first `while` loop - marked by the comments - '**we need to loop to a point on the plan that is within a certain distance of the robot**'.

In this section, we are looping over the points in the `global_plan` until `sq_dist <= sq_dist_threshold`. Shouldn't this cause the first `while` loop to break immediately because the first point in the `global_plan` would be the one that is closest to the bot?

```
bool transformGlobalPlan(
      const tf2_ros::Buffer& tf,
      const std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& global_plan,
      const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& global_pose,
      const costmap_2d::Costmap2D& costmap,
      const std::string& global_frame,
      std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& transformed_plan){
    transformed_plan.clear();

    if (global_plan.empty()) {
      ROS_ERROR("Received plan with zero length");
      return false;
    }

    const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& plan_pose = global_plan[0];
    try {
      // get plan_to_global_transform from plan frame to global_frame
      geometry_msgs::TransformStamped plan_to_global_transform = tf.lookupTransform(global_frame, ros::Time(),
          plan_pose.header.frame_id, plan_pose.header.stamp, plan_pose.header.frame_id, ros::Duration(0.5));

      //let's get the pose of the robot in the frame of the plan
      geometry_msgs::PoseStamped robot_pose;
      tf.transform(global_pose, robot_pose, plan_pose.header.frame_id);

      //we'll discard points on the plan that are outside the local costmap
      double dist_threshold = std::max(costmap.getSizeInCellsX() * costmap.getResolution() / 2.0,
                                       costmap.getSizeInCellsY() * costmap.getResolution() / 2.0);

      unsigned int i = 0;
      double sq_dist_threshold = dist_threshold * dist_threshold;
      double sq_dist = 0;

      //we need to loop to a point on the plan that is within a certain distance of the robot
      while(i < (unsigned int)global_plan.size()) {
        double x_diff = robot_pose.pose.position.x - global_plan[i].pose.position.x;
        double y_diff = robot_pose.pose.position.y - global_plan[i].pose.position.y;
        sq_dist = x_diff * x_diff + y_diff * y_diff;
        if (sq_dist <= sq_dist_threshold) {
          break;
        }
        ++i;
      }

      geometry_msgs::PoseStamped newer_pose;

      //now we'll transform until points are outside of our distance threshold
      while(i < (unsigned int)global_plan.size() && sq_dist <= sq_dist_threshold) {
        const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& pose = global_plan[i];
        tf2::doTransform(pose, newer_pose, plan_to_global_transform);

        transformed_plan.push_back(newer_pose);

        double x_diff = robot_pose.pose.position.x - global_plan[i].pose.position.x;
        double y_diff = robot_pose.pose.position.y - global_plan[i].pose.position.y;
        sq_dist = x_diff * x_diff + y_diff * y_diff;

        ++i;
      }
    }
    catch(tf2::LookupException& ex) {
      ROS_ERROR("No Transform available Error: %s\n", ex.what());
      return false;
    }
    catch(tf2::ConnectivityException& ex) {
      ROS_ERROR("Connectivity Error: %s\n", ex.what());
      return false;
    }
    catch(tf2::ExtrapolationException& ex) {
      ROS_ERROR("Extrapolation Error: %s\n", ex.what());
      if (!global_plan.empty())
        ROS_ERROR("Global Frame: %s Plan Frame size %d: %s\n", global_frame.c_str(), (unsigned int)global_plan.size(), global_plan[0].header.frame_id.c_str());

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382606/doubt-regarding-the-base_local_planner::transformglobalplan()-function/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If we ignore error conditions, the global plan is created before the robot starts moving. Once the robot has followed the global plan for a little while, some x,y points are behind the robot and some points are in front of the current robot position. "Used up" points don't disappear just because the robot passes them.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-07-15**:
Makes sense. Thanks!